# cannot find symbol when compiling java when compiling an external class

Tags: java

When I try to call Programmer class from Main class an error comes up, saying that it cannot find symbol Programmer.
**NOTE** : Programmer.java and Main.java are in the same folder (package).

Main.java

```
public class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Scanner scann = new Scanner(System.in);
        Programmer john = new Programmer();
        System.out.println(john);
  }

 }
```

Programmer.java:

```
public class Programmer {
  String language = "java";
  String framework = "Spring";
}
```

Result of java main.java command

```
main.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Programmer john = new Programmer();
        ^
symbol:   class Programmer
location: class Main
main.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Programmer john = new Programmer();
                              ^
symbol:   class Programmer
location: class Main
2 errors
```

error: compilation failed

Comment: Have you compiled the `Programmer` class?

Answer (score 2):

Single file mode, where you just type 'java YourClass.java' needs all of the dependencies compiled first.

```
javac Main.java
java Main
```

That should get your program running, and to compile the additional class file. If you prefer to use the single source file.

```
javac Programmer.java
java Main.java
```

Should work although if you have a leftover main.class on your class path you could have an issue.

**This is for java 11 and later when single source mode was introduced.